# How to prove the convergence in probability?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

$Y_n$, $n = 1, 2, ...$ is a sequence of nonnegative random variables with their means converging to $0$. Can we show $Y_n \rightarrow 0$ in probability? Thanks!

Comment: If $X>0$ and $E[X]<\epsilon$, can you bound $P\{X > 2\epsilon\}$ ??

Comment: In fact $L_p$ convergence implies Convergence in probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Use Markov's Inequality, i.e. for all $\epsilon>0$
$$P(X_n>\epsilon)\leqslant \frac{E(X_n)}{\epsilon}\to0$$